# How to change the styling of Buttons to a Path object?

Tags: wpf, button, path, styles, windows-store-apps

Using WPF for Windows Store Apps:

I'm looking for a possibility to get the shape of my Path object as the appearance for a Button.

```
Path path = new Path();
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Style = path.Style; // searching for something like this
```

Edit:
I tried it with Button.Content like this, but also failed:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <Path>
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathFigure StartPoint="0,0">
                        <ArcSegment Point="200,0"
                            IsLargeArc="False"
                            RotationAngle="180"
                            Size="200,200"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                        />
                        <LineSegment Point="0,0"/>
....Leaving all the Closing Tags
```

Shouldn't this give me a Button shaped like a half circle? In VisualStudio I still get rectangular Buttons.

Comment: Could you write in detail what you need? `Path` to the button, it is in `Button.Content` or in `Button` template? Show your XAML.

Comment: number one, there's no such thing as `WPF for Windows Store Apps`. You must be talking about WinRT XAML which is NOT WPF. Number two, **Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. That's what XAML if for.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML:

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <Path Data="path data here..."/>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

In code, you want to set the Content of the Button to whatever you want to appear.

```
Button myButton = new Button();
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Data = ...
myButton.Content = myPath;
```

Do yourself a favor though and get a book on Windows Store application development.  I highly recommend this work by Pete Brown:
[http://www.amazon.com/Windows-Store-App-Development-XAML/dp/1617290947](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1617290947)

It will more than pay for itself in the time it will save you.  Development using XAML whether in WPF/Silverlight/Windows Phone/Windows Store apps is very different from the traditional way applications are developed.

Cheers,
Dave